# How do I create a custom login page in Lightning using Napili template

Tags: lightning, napili, login, page-template

Napili automatically assigns login to its own Login page. The template does not appear to allow use of a Custom Login page. Also, the assigned Login page does not import the CMS Connect headers and footers. I need to be able to either customize the login page template to include the CMS Connect content or assign the login to a custom page of my choosing that uses the Customer service template.

Answer (score 3):

You don't create your own login page, you modify the existing one by using your own components and (if you like) your own theme and layout.

See https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_login_self_reg_lightning.htm&type=5

> Each community comes with a default set of Login pages: Check
>   Password, Forgot Password, Login, Login Error, Register. Each has a
>   standard Lightning component that drives this functionality. You can
>   add code logic to customize the login experience per your company and
>   community’s requirements.
>
> From Setup, enter Lightning Components in the Quick Find box, then
>   select Lightning Components under Develop. From the list of
>   components, click on the one you want to customize. For example, to
>   customize the login experience, click loginForm. On the Lightning
>   component detail page, click Developer Console. Follow the
>   instructions in the code to expose the component in Community Builder.
>   Add custom code logic and save your changes as a new custom component.
>   Go back to Community Builder in your community and bring up the Login
>   page from the list of pages. The custom component you created should
>   display in the list of components.